# Compiling scss in React application adds only classes in .css file that are used in React application

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am using `style-loader` with `css-loader` in React application. Each time I change/update my code, wether it is JS or SCSS, my client.js and client.css are rebuilt.

Each time that happens, webpack config/plugins do a very cool feature. Any class that is not used in React is not added to final .css file. Awesome right!

But I need all the classes to be added in. Even the once that are not used. 
I am migrating from React to Twig and I copy paste generated HTML from React application into Twig and modify React components to have all the static HTML in twig leaving only some small interactive bits in React.

FYI That was a business decision as ReactJS was server rendered for best SEO optimisation, but it does not make sense in our case.

If you know a better way to migrate ReactJS application into Twig please let me know! I think biggest challenge will be optimising classes name conventions from React into Twig. At the moment I am coping the fully generated name like `<div class="src-components-common-Page-___Page__page">`.